# How properly include dependencies to artifacts in UML use cases

Tags: uml, use-case

I want to express a use case diagram involving two stakeholders, where one stakeholder's use case is co-depending on an artifact, that is produced by the other stakeholder's use case.

In the following (minimal simplified) example I try to express this using the associations for dependency, which also are used in use case diagrams to express `<<include>>` and `<<extend>>`:

[image]

Is this a valid model? It feels not right since the associations are somewhat ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifacts aren't shown on a Use Case diagram. A valid, compliant Use Case diagram only shows Actors, Use Cases, and relationships (between Actors, between Use Cases, and between an Actor and a Use Case).

If you want to show inputs and outputs and stay within the UML language, consider using Activity Diagrams to show more details about particular Use Cases. You can show inputs and outputs on an Activity Diagram.